# Python Converting hex string to decimal values

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, utf-8, hex

I am given strings structured as such: `"\x0C\x00Maximilianus\xf4\x01"` and I would like to dynamically extract first two and last two bytes and convert them to decimals. The encoding for this should be UTF-8 little-endian unsigned.

`"\x0C\x00"` equals 12

`"\xf4\x01"` equals 500

I am not able to find any function that would be able to do that. Also replacing "\x" in the string doesn't work as I cannot manipulate with escape characters.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you really want decimals? Or ints?

Comment: And you say you get strings but you're also talking about encoding, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: how did you create this structure ? If you will know how it was created then you will know how to convert it back. For example : if you used `struct.pack()` to create it then use `struct.unpack()` to convert it back.

Comment: BTW: string `Maximilianus` has 12 chars so `"\x0C\x00"` can be information how long is string and it can be some system to send data in network

Comment: `print(struct.unpack('hh', b"\x0C\x00\xf4\x01"))` gives `(12, 500)`

Comment: @furas I haven't created it... and yes the first two bytes tell the lenght of the name.

Comment: you can use `struct.unpack()` to convert first two bytes, next use this value to get string, and next use again `struct` to convert two bytes. But it looks like something similar to [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/)

Comment: if you didn't create it then where did you get it ? Is this some part of HTML or JavaScript? Maybe there is information what tool was used to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to get numbers.

Using table [Format Characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) you can see you need `"h"` to convert 2-bytes integer.
You can eventually use `"<h"` to make sure it will use `little-endian`

```
import struct

# convert to bytes
data = "\x0C\x00Maximilianus\xf4\x01".encode('latin1')

# get short integer
number = struct.unpack('<h', data[:2])[0]
print('number:', number)

# skip number
data = data[2:]

# get string
#text = struct.unpack(f'{number}s', data[:number])[0] # use `number` to create `"12s"`
#print('text:', text.decode())
print('text:', data[:number].decode())

# skip string
data = data[number:]

# get short integer
number = struct.unpack('<h', data[:2])[0]
print('number:', number)
```

---

**BTW:** it looks similar to [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/) so maybe there is special module for this but I don't know it.

Comment: `data = "\x0C\x00Maximilianus\xf4\x01".encode('latin1')` this was the line I was looking for. Then I can do `int.from_bytes(data[:2],byteorder="little")` to get the first part and `int.from_bytes(data[-2:],byteorder="little")` to get the last part.

Comment: you could put your comment as answer - it can be useful for other users.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my final solution with the help from [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas):

```
data = "\x0C\x00Maximilianus\xf4\x01".encode('latin1')
name_len = int.from_bytes(data[:2],byteorder="little")
ending = int.from_bytes(data[-2:],byteorder="little")

print(name_len) # --> 12
print(ending) # --> 500
```